# Get the last entered id from a table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTYO8.png)I have an employee table. In that table I have n number of loan.. Now I want to select all the employees with his last taken loan value and date.. can anyone help me out in this.

There's what I've done so far:

```
SELECT employee_id,employee_name,department_name, 
       designation_name,PF_type,PF_number,Opening_balance,
       MAX(Loan_id),MAX(loan_date), MAX(loan_amount)  
FROM single_roww1
GROUP BY employee_id
```

I tried group by, limit and order by for this but of no use... I also tried to take the last occurence of the employee_id that also didn't work..

Comment: Hi @kowshiga! Welcome to StackOverFlow. Could you please paste the query you already tried? So the community will better help you about. You can also read some tips about how to ask here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: SELECT employee_id,employee_name,department_name, designation_name,PF_type,PF_number,Opening_balance, MAX(Loan_id),MAX(loan_date), MAX(loan_amount) FROM single_roww1 
GROUP BY employee_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: to get the full row of max id:

```
SELECT *
FROM loan
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT max(id) max_id
   FROM loan
   GROUP BY employee_id) x ON x.max_id = loan.id
group by employee_id;
```

I have to mention that your DB table design without primary key isn't well designed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTYO8.png

Comment: Hi friend thank you for your response... I have tried that but it is taking max date and amount.. But I want the row with max id

Comment: SELECT *
FROM single_roww1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(Loan_id) max_id
    FROM single_roww1
    GROUP BY employee_id) i ON i.max_id = single_roww1.Loan_id

Comment: This query returns more than 1000 rows .. I have only 380 employees

Comment: please add your table structure with sample of the data to the question

Comment: I have added that see the image link at the starting of my question.. In that image you can able to see double entries for same employees.. that is because they have taken loan more than one time.. Now i want to select the single row each employee with his last takent loan details

Comment: @kowshiga what's the primary key of your table?

Comment: I  dont have a primary key

Comment: I in the query you have given above, I get exactly 380 rows

Comment: i have tried the above query it is working... thank you very much

Comment: yeah sure... but I don't know how to votes.. My vote is not recording

Answer (score 0):

If only the row containing the last loan_id is required than a correlated sub query is what you want

```
SELECT *
FROM single_roww1 SR
WHERE LOAN_ID = (SELECT MAX(LOAN_ID) FROM single_roww1 WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = SR.EMPLOYEE_ID);
```

Comment: this query gives 381 rows

Answer (score 0):

With a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT s.employee_id, s.employee_name, s.department_name, 
       s.designation_name, s.PF_type, s.PF_number, s.Opening_balance,
       s.Loan_id, s.loan_date, s.loan_amount  
FROM single_roww1 s
WHERE s.Loan_id = (SELECT MAX(Loan_id) FROM single_roww1 WHERE employee_id = s.employee_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

> last taken loan value and date

You seem to want:

```
SELECT sr.*
FROM single_roww1 sr
WHERE sr.loan_date = (SELECT MAX(sr2.load_date)
                      FROM single_roww1 sr2
                      WHERE sr2.employee_id = sr.employee_id
                     );
```

This assumes shat `loan_date` has a proper date/time type in the database (despite what the data in the image looks like).

For performance, you want an index on `(employee_id, load_date)`.

Note that if an employee has multiple loans on the same date, this will retrieve the last one.